# gem jquery-ui-rails couldn't find file 'jquery.ui.all' (

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, rubygems

I'm trying to add jquery ui datepicker to my application with help of [jquery-ui-rails gem](https://github.com/joliss/jquery-ui-rails). I've checked [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/213-calendars-revised) I seem to do everything right, but i get an error upon application startup
`couldn't find file 'jquery.ui.all'`

Gemfile(end of it, tried to include gem in the assets group but no luck):

```
gem 'backbone-on-rails'
gem "jquery-ui-rails"
```

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require underscore
//= require backbone
//= require svitla_test
//= require_tree ../templates
//= require_tree ./models
//= require_tree ./collections
//= require_tree ./views
//= require_tree ./routers
//= require_tree .
//= require jquery.ui.all
```

application.css

```
*= require jquery.ui.all
*= require_self
*= require_tree .
```

Comment: try putting it after jquery

Comment: Where exactly do you mean?

Comment: I've tried in application.js & application.css to put require lines at the bottom of require block. still get that error.

Comment: I mean, try putting `//= require jquery.ui.all` right after `//= require jquery`

Comment: Yep, done the trick, thanks!

Comment: I'll put that as answer, so other will get help as well

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Put `//= require jquery.ui.all` right after `//= require jquery` so it will look like this

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.ui.all
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require underscore
//= require backbone
//= require svitla_test
//= require_tree ../templates
//= require_tree ./models
//= require_tree ./collections
//= require_tree ./views
//= require_tree ./routers
//= require_tree .
```

note that the order of which these lines are written is the order which these files are loaded.. So if you call a `jquery-ui` function before it knows what `jquery-ui` is, most likely you need to change the order a bit..

It is usually good to put infrastructure files before your own files to avoid these kind of problems

Answer (score 21):

At version 5.0 it has been changed. You can read more about it [here](https://github.com/joliss/jquery-ui-rails#require-everything).

**version 5.0**:

application.js:

```
//= require jquery-ui
```

application.css:

```
/*
 *= require jquery-ui
 */
```

**version 4.x** (I'm sure about 4.2.0 and 4.2.1):

application.js:

```
//= require jquery.ui.all
```

application.css:

```
/*
 *= require jquery.ui.all
 */
```