# rails active admin deployment : couldn't find file 'jquery-ui'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, activeadmin, assets

when trying to deploy with capistrano, when capistrano use command
bundle exec rake

```
    RAILS_ENV=production 
    RAILS_GROUPS=assets 
    assets:precompile
```

I have this error

```
couldn't find file 'jquery-ui'
  (in /home/umbrosus/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@gancxadebebi/gems/activeadmin-0.5.1/app/assets/javascripts/active_admin/base.js:2)
```

Before it was working well, but I tried to update to 0.6 and then I started to have this error. I came back to 0.5.1 and the error is still there. Do I do something bad ?

thanks

Comment: I'm having the same issue on my local version. Using Ruby 2.0.0-p0

Comment: either downgrade or so:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15874265/gem-jquery-ui-rails-couldnt-find-file-jquery-ui-all

Answer (score 118, accepted):

The "jquery-rails" gem recently removed jQuery UI.

https://github.com/rails/jquery-rails/commit/2fdcdb2633cbc6426d412c050200fc31d14b9a3b

They recommend using the jquery-ui-rails gem.

There is an [active pull request](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/pull/2233) (as of this writing) to add that gem as a dependency. However, the developers of ActiveAdmin have stated that they are "[locking it down until we officially drop support for Rails 3.0](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/pull/2430#issuecomment-23040221)". The version they are locked to is `jquery-rails < 3.0.0`.

In the meantime, just modify your Gemfile:

<strike>gem "jquery-ui-rails"</strike> *Not recommended, see @Kevin's comment below*

Or you can downgrade your version of jquery-rails:

```
gem "jquery-rails", "< 3.0.0"
```

Or you can pull from their Github master branch. They have applied a temporary fix.

```
gem "activeadmin", github: "gregbell/active_admin"
```

Comment: To save frustration, I'd recommend the second solution. The `gem "jquery-ui-rails"` named their `jquery-ui` file `jqueryui`, so ActiveAdmin will still have a loading error if you go that route.

Comment: Downgrading "jquery-rails" to "2.3.0" fixed this issue from my end.
On Rails 3.2.13, btw.

Answer (score 31):

Well, there is no need to downgrade `jquery-rails` to `2.3.0` or specify a GitHub branch. Just use `jquery-ui-rails`. To workaround the file name differences:

Simply create `app/assets/javascripts/jquery-ui.js`

```
//= require jquery.ui.all
```

Create `app/assets/stylesheets/jquery-ui.css`

```
/*
 *= require jquery.ui.all
 */
```

These load the correct files to satisfy ActiveAdmin

Comment: I like this better, because I generally like using rubygems as a source rather than the master branch on github.

Comment: Just followed these instructions and it worked perfectly - thanks.

Comment: I liked your solution because I use other gems that depend on jquery-ui > 3.0.0

Comment: I like this solution as well because I need to use jquery-rails > 3.0.0 and jquery-ui-rails.  However, I'm running into a dependancy issue . . . `Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "jquery-rails":
  In Gemfile:
    activeadmin (= 0.6.1) depends on
      jquery-rails (< 3, >= 1.0.0)

    jquery-rails (3.0.4)`.  How can I get around this???

Comment: @chuckw I have `activeadmin 0.6.0` in my `Gemfile.lock` and it doesn't have the rule `jquery-rails (<3)`. `activeadmin 0.6.0` and `jquery-rails 3.0.4` seem to coexist well for me. So try changing your ActiveAdmin line to `gem 'activeadmin', '0.6.0'` to freeze it (assume you don't need ActiveAdmin `0.6.1`'s new features)? You should probably report this to ActiveAdmin's issue tracker separately.

Comment: I'm using Rails 4.0.8, and i don't have app/assets/js but app/assets/javascript. Does it matter? I tried both folder, neither worked tbh. My gemfile uses `gem 'jquery-ui-rails'` and `gem 'jquery-rails', '>=3.0.4'`

Comment: @oasisweng I think `app/assets/js` was a typo but widely understood by audience. Just checked on Rails 4.1 the actual folder name should be `app/assets/javascripts`

Answer (score 11):

Though the Pull request has been merged into AA by now, you will still have this problem if you work with the latest release of AA. I don't like to force JQuery-rails down to version 2.3.0 so here's an alternative solution to the problem:
In the `active_admin.js` file replace

```
//= require active_admin/base
```

with

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.ui.core
//= require jquery.ui.widget
//= require jquery.ui.datepicker
//= require active_admin/application
```

kudos to [Fred](https://github.com/fred) for providing that solution [here](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/issues/2232#issuecomment-18683297).

Comment: couldn't find file 'jquery.ui.core'

Answer (score 1):

Downgrading "jquery-rails" to "2.3.0" fixed this issue for me as well.

Comment: Anybody got a full answer which does not involve downgrading jquery-rails?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the jquery issue was due to a gem I was using.  I wasn't using jquery directly, so adding app/assets/js/jquery-ui.js to my project didn't help.

Adding gem "jquery-rails", "< 3.0.0" to my gemfile fixed it, but I got an issue with turbolinks immediately after that, which is easy enough to fix...

My final gemfile:

```
# Temporary fix for jquery issue
gem "jquery-rails", "< 3.0.0"
gem 'turbolinks'
```

... easy peasy

Answer (score 0):

I know this is already solved. But I want to give one more solution to this that worked for me.

I am running Rails 4.0.8 when having this issue.

I simply remove explicit version number for jquery-rails gem jquery-ui-rails gem.

Mine looks like this essentially:

```
# js
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
gem 'jquery-rails'

# rails admin
gem 'rails_admin'
```

`Gemfile.lock` kinda figured out the correct version for all three gems automatically.