# i am using active admin but it comes an error couldn't find file 'jquery-ui'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

Hello I am using: `'http'rails', '3.1.0'`

**# Bundle edge Rails instead:**

```
gem 'mysql2'
gem 'activeadmin'
```

**# Gems used only for assets and not required**

**# in production environments by default.**

```
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails', "  ~> 3.1.0"
  gem 'coffee-rails', "~> 3.1.0"
  gem 'uglifier'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
```

Comment: Have a look here -   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16844411/rails-active-admin-deployment-couldnt-find-file-jquery-ui

Answer (score 0):

Use specific version of `gem "jquery-rails", "~> 2.3.0"`

or

you can use `gem "jquery-ui-rails"` for jquery-ui . For more information please visit the git repository

To require all jQuery UI modules, add the following to your application.js:

```
//= require jquery.ui.all
```

Also add the jQuery UI CSS to your application.css:

```
/*
 *= require jquery.ui.all
 */
```

Hope this could help you.
For creat new admin users:

```
AdminUser.create!(:email => 'your_email', :password => 'password', :password_confirmation => 'password')
```

Comment: @venu Is above answer working for you ?

Comment: ya its work for me..but i want to create user as a admin if give me any solution

Comment: Then accept above answer.

Comment: Are you using devise or what ? and also for user model do you have role column in Users Table ? @venu

Comment: i am new for rails so asking how to create user as admin we create the only admin.but i want create specific  user or some one as admin ..

Comment: AdminUser.create!(:email => 'admin@example.com', :password => 'password', :password_confirmation => 'password')

Comment: in model we want to riht the code

Comment: Run it on rails console

Comment: please give 1step to last step how write means in controll or model .if r  u given that i want to Patrice that code and implement  the anther one..if u dont mind

Comment: Could you please accept above answer by click on the right symbol just below the vote in answer ?

Comment: @venu run rails console on terminal, then paste above query there. And please accept above answer for jquery related issue.