# ActiveAdmin can't find jquery.ui.datepicker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin, webfaction

```
ActionView::Template::Error (couldn't find file 'jquery.ui.datepicker'
  (in /home/raimat/webapps/keita/gems/bundler/gems/active_admin-2ae0a9e09bf9/app/assets/javascripts/active_admin/base.js.coffee:2)):
     7:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag params[:controller] %>
     8:   <link rel='stylesheet' href='/assets/typicons.min.css'/>
     9:
    10:   <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
    11:   <%= javascript_include_tag 'ckeditor/ckeditor.js' %>
    12:
    13:
  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:10:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__42414357695359850_50936120'
  app/controllers/home_controller.rb:15:in `index'
```

This only occurs when I try to deploy my app at webfaction (Both Production and development). *I've tried it on two different local machines, and it goes as smooth as it should.* 
Edit: I removed Gemfile.lock on my local machine, and now I get this error there as well.

Tried the solutions found at [rails active admin deployment : couldn't find file 'jquery-ui'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16844411/rails-active-admin-deployment-couldnt-find-file-jquery-ui) but I still stand with the bug.

I use Rails 4.0.2
ActiveAdmin at master branch
I need jquery-rails > ~> 3.1.0 for another gem

Tried adding gem `jquery-rails-ui`, but still nothing..

Ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was running into the same problem.  Noticed there was an upgrade to jquery-ui-rails a couple of days ago (July 3, 2014) so I downgraded to the previous version and that fixed my problems

In gemfile

```
gem 'jquery-ui-rails', '~> 4.2.1'
```

In application.js

```
//= require jquery-ui
```

Comment: At work right now, I just wanna go home and try this out. This bug has annoyed more than enough already!

Comment: Going back to jquery-ui-rails 4.2.1 worked for me also. Seems to be a compatibility issue with jquery-ui-rails v5.0.0 and the current master branch of ActiveAdmin. Did anyone open up a github issue for this yet on the repo?

Comment: Update To previous comment -- Here is the [pull request to fix it](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/pull/3255)

Comment: This fixed it for me. All of Jquery UI wan't loading in ActiveAdmin, going back to 4.2.1 fixed that issue.